# jQuery returns XML node fine the first time, but the second time i call it, its empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have this XML in an externally loaded file via AJAX and jQuery:

```
<project>
    <title>Title Name 2</title>
    <tags>Tag1.Tag2</tags>
    <image src="img/portfolio/better/better01.jpg" title="Image title" tags="Tag1.Tag2"></image>
    <image src="img/portfolio/better/better02.jpg" title="Image title" tags="Tag1.Tag2"></image>
    <thumb src="img/portfolio/better/better01.jpg" title="Image title" tags="Tag1.Tag2"></thumb>
    <copy>
        <columnOne>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lobortis accumsan purus. Nulla at arcu est. Mauris iaculis ses tincidunt odio cursus accumsan. Morbi quis interdumes massa. Nulla eu ipsum nunc, necs gravida metus. Pelle ntesque utes ligula est nec ullamcorper nulla.</p>
            <p>Cras id hendrerit velit. Suspendisse arscibus libero. Pellentesqueses habitant morbi trtique senctus et netus etsuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam sagittise euismod velit, quis pharetra lacus ibulum mollis saewesty.</p>
        </columnOne>
        <columnTwo>
            <p>Morbi quis inteumes massa. Nulla eu ipsum nunc, necs gravida metus. Pelle ntesqueessy ligula est nec ullamcorper nulla</p>
        </columnTwo>
     </copy>
</project>
```

There are several  nodes within the XML document. I have pushed all the  nodes into an array called 'project_array'. When i do :

```
console.log(project_array[0].text());
```

I get:

```
Title Name 2
    Tag1.Tag2







            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lobortis accumsan purus. Nulla at arcu est. Mauris iaculis ses tincidunt odio cursus accumsan. Morbi quis interdumes massa. Nulla eu ipsum nunc, necs gravida metus. Pelle ntesque utes ligula est nec ullamcorper nulla.
            Cras id hendrerit velit. Suspendisse arscibus libero. Pellentesqueses habitant morbi trtique senctus et netus etsuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam sagittise euismod velit, quis pharetra lacus ibulum mollis saewesty.


            Morbi quis inteumes massa. Nulla eu ipsum nunc, necs gravida metus. Pelle ntesqueessy ligula est nec ullamcorper nulla
```

Which is what I expect, the entire contents of the nodes within 'project'. The second time I call it I get just the 'title' and 'tags' node, and the 'columnOne' and 'columnTwo' nodes are empty.

Head banging scenario. Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: hard to tell without any of your actual code to understands how you are calling this array, and what happens to the array in between calls.

Comment: @MikeBrant `code` var bodyCopy = projects_array[n],
           title = projects_array[n].find('title'),
           tags = projects_array[n].find('tags');

Comment: @MikeBrant `code` var bodyCopy = projects_array[n];
console.log($(bodyCopy).text()); `code`

Works first time, but not second time.

Initial code just iterates through the xml and pushes each project node into projects_array. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you populated `project_array`, calling `project_array[0].text()` might actually be removing the `text` content, though I'm not sure why `<title>` and `<tags>` would come through the next time.

Try using `$(project_array[0]).clone().text()`, storing it in a variable, and using that variable for repeat references instead.

Comment: So i tried a few ways of implementing your .clone() tip, and had no luck, so i revisit tonight with $(bodyCopy.find('columOne')).clone(); And this works a treat! Thanks, saved my bacon. I had no idea that using .find() on an array would return and also remove that text from the array. Must remember that one! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` is a method to be used on jQuery Object

If `project_array` its a array of nodes why are using `project_array[0].text()`

Looks like it should be

```
console.log($(project_array[0]).text())
```